# Ruby interpolation within a css selector Capybara

Tags: css, ruby, capybara

I am getting invalid selector errors when trying to find an element with capybara

This works

```
page.find("#widget_amount_Standard")
```

However when I try and use

```
credit_type = "Standard"
page.find("#widget_amount_'#{credit_type}'") OR
page.find("#widget_amount_"#{credit_type}"") OR
page.find("div[id^="widget_amount_'#{credit_type}'"]")
```

I still get errors, where am I going wrong with the syntax, interpolation is always carried out with double quotes I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
page.find("#widget_amount_#{credit_type}")
```

Comment: you know what I just found that out :-), but i dont understand how it knows its interpolated without `""`.

Comment: Look closely, there are double quotes around the whole string.

Comment: ah ok, for some reason i thought it might have got confused with the extra `#` but then with the `{}` it knows :-), thanks, silly thinking on my part